# Using Basic & Token authentication in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization, access-token, basic-authentication

I am developing an application where I expect two type of authorization requests. Refer to the picture below

1) Both request are accessing the same resources.

2) Both request are accessing the the same endpoint.

3) First request is already authenticated and only expiry of token will be verified.

4) Second request will be authenticated before given access to the resource.

[image: Request Flow]

What I know about Spring security is, that it revolves around configuring secure and non-secured URLs. In our case although only authenticated users can access the resource, authentication is not required for first request as it is already authenticated. How can I set up different security configurations for these two requests. Any suggestions are welcome?

Comment: So you want two different authorization server, isn't it ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna yeah something like that. I didn't understand what you mean by server?

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary I think its better to implement your own Spring security authentication filter that will extend 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'. Set your this custom filter in place of 'BasicAuthenticationFilter' in configuration. This filter should check if there is any token in request header, if exists, check its expiry, otherwise forward request to its parent method(super.doFilterInternal()) for default authentication(basic). What do you mean by token-based?? Is this a Spring OAuth token or your own custom token?

Comment: @Afridi it is a JWT token.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary ok, is it your own custom token, or the one provided by Spring OAuth Jwt?? Spring OAuth is validating(both expiry, user validations etc) this token automatically if you are sending it with Bearer  prefix